# Translate javascript modules

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader, quickjs

I was trying to run some NodeJS code using QickJS and NectarJS, and I stumble in an old question I have, how to import modules.

In special, `qjs -m <source-js>` loads ES6 modules, and expect `import` `export` statements,, instead of require, and writing `module.exports`, or `exports`.

Also I use an builtin `std` module (that cannot be resolved by node_module).

For the first example I changed the code manually, but I would like to have a script to do the transformations. I expected this to be doable with webpack, but I can't find how.

### Example

main.js

```js
const h = require('./hello.js');
h.sayHello();
```

hello.js

```js
const h = require('./print.js');
function sayHello(){
  h.print("Hello");
}
module.exports = {sayHello};
```

print.js

```js
module.exports = {
  print(s) {
    console.log(s);
  }
}
```

I can run this with the command `node main.js`, but `qjs -m main.js`, will fail with *'require' is not defined*

Answer (score 0):

QuickJS does not support CommonJS-modules. Instead it supports native JS-Modules following the ECMA-standard. So you either

1. transpile from CommonJS into std-modules and then use `import/export` instead of `require`. As you mentioned webpack, that'll do fine. ESBuild can transpile from CommonJS(.cjs) to ES-Module(.mjs) too. Or
2. you might try the require-loader for QuickJS - which i found here  https://github.com/IvanGaravito/quickjs-require.

regards, Andreas

Comment: Welcome Andreas.
Your answer is not complete. You mentioned a few solutions, now can you show the steps to apply them to the example I gave.